# Should sub user types have a separate models on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Say I have two types of users, `merchant` and `consumer`, that share a base table `user` for common data such as email/password.

I have separate tables `merchant_data` and `consumer_data` for data specific to the user types. More info about this in [my question here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117781/some-users-can-have-a-fixed-amount-of-additional-fields-eav-or-not/117833#117833)

On top of this, each user subtype has different relationship with other entities in the database.

**In terms of best practice, should I have a separate models for `merchant` and `consumer`?** i.e. Merchant_model extends User_model (which extends MY_Model)

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion if u have just type and basic info difference between them then no need to have seperate model as it does not need much code which is different from each other, but if u have much difference between them in terms of model function then best solution is to have extra model.